# Bootstrap popover containing html links showing up only one time

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, popover

That's my first question here, I've searched on stackoverflow but couldn't succeed to find the proper answer.

So, I've implemented a bootstrap popover which content is showing up only at the first click.
My problem happen when I open this popover a second time : the content is not showing up.

Here is the html code:

```
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus">
        yolo
    </a>

    <div id="clickGoogle" style="display:none;" class="open_modal">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="add_banner.php?id=<?php echo $membre['id'];?>" class="openPopup" style="text-decoration: none">Change banner</a><hr>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="add_profile.php?id=<?php echo $membre['id'];?>" class="openPopup" style="text-decoration: none">Change avatar</a><hr>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="settings.php" class="openPopup" style="text-decoration: none">Edit profile</a>
    </div>
```

Followed by the JS code:

```
$(function() { 
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      html:true,
      content : function() {
        $('#clickGoogle').css({'display':'block'});
        return $('#clickGoogle');
      }        
    });
});
```

I con't figure out WHY the #clickGoogle doesn't show up when I want to open the popover a second time...??

I hope I'm sufficiently clear in my explanations, if no, tell me!

Thank you for your help on that ;)

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(function() { 
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      html:true,
      content : function() {
        $('#clickGoogle').css({'display':'block'});
        return $('#clickGoogle');
      }        
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus">
  yolo
</a>


<div id="clickGoogle" style="display:none;" class="open_modal">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="add_banner.php?id=<?php echo $membre['id'];?>" class="openPopup" style="text-decoration: none">Change banner</a><hr>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="add_profile.php?id=<?php echo $membre['id'];?>" class="openPopup" style="text-decoration: none">Change avatar</a><hr>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="settings.php" class="openPopup" style="text-decoration: none">Edit profile</a>
</div>
</body>
</html
```

EDIT:

The solution provided is working but is at the same time deactivating the links, so I’m looking for another solution

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you add your code in a snippet so we can test it and see where is the probleme ? If we cannot replicate it, it's hard to help you. The snippet is the 7 icon from the left when you edit your question.

Comment: Done ;)
First try I'm using a snippet : awesome!
So do you have any ideas on my problem?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but it seams that your popup is removing the content element from the DOM on popup destroy. Since you are passing your element via reference, that might be why it is removed aswell.

To fix that, I've simply returned the HTML of the element, using the Jquery function `html()` rather than the element itself.

Note here that you don't need to change the css anymore.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(function() { 
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      html:true,
      content : function() {
        return $('#clickGoogle').html();
      }        
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus">
  yolo
</a>


<div id="clickGoogle" style="display:none;" class="open_modal">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="add_banner.php?id=<?php echo $membre['id'];?>" class="openPopup" style="text-decoration: none">Change banner</a><hr>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="add_profile.php?id=<?php echo $membre['id'];?>" class="openPopup" style="text-decoration: none">Change avatar</a><hr>
  <a href="https://google.com/" data-href="settings.php" class="openPopup" style="text-decoration: none">Edit profile</a>
</div>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: You've seen right on that, I've corrected with your html() function and the popover is now showing up each time I'm clicking on it.

But I have another problem showing up because of that modification: links are not active anymore...

Comment: Well I'm not sure how your code works but from what you gave, every link is pointing to nothing ( `href="javascript:void(0)"` ) . You could try to change it to `href="settings.php"` instead.

Comment: Nope, still not...
I've tried by replacing by a simple google url, but nothing : the text is showing but not the link
Don't you think it could be related to the "style="display:none"??

Comment: The link seams to be working in the example above. Obviously it is not going to render the page because we're in an IFrame but you can see it correctly change the url. Your problem might be somewhere else and I can't help you with that,.

Comment: Ah!! I think I have something:
The "clickGoogle" div has a "display:none" style, and the first code I posted was modificating this display as "display:block"
So I assume I will need something to re-toggle the display as "none" when the popover si closed, don't you think?

Comment: The `display:none` is just an instruction for your front-end. Since we are using the HTML of this element for your popup, it should matter. You can try it out though.

Comment: It seems not to have any influence on that... That’s really really weird?! I’m lost...